# How to show grid labels when using starred pspicture?

Tags: pstricks

I need grid labels even when I use `\pspicture*`. How to do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\begin{document}
\figure[h]\centering
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](1,1)
\psline(-1,-1)(2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\caption{without clipping}
\endfigure


\figure[h]\centering
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](1,1)
\psline(-1,-1)(2,2)
\end{pspicture*}
\caption{with clipping}
\endfigure

\end{document}
```

Comment: As you may notice, the dots of your grid are cut off at the outer edges in the second figure. This suggests to me that the labels are there, but covered up due to the effect of the `pspicture*` environment. This same effect is what gives you your clipping. I haven't yet found a way around this, but I'm looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](1,1)
\rput[lb](0,0){%
  \begin{pspicture*}(1,1)
  \psline(-1,-1)(2,2)
  \end{pspicture*}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]